# Have iPad with iOS 7 ask for network password

Tags: ipad, ios

I'd like to have my iPad prompt me for my WiFi password when it's turned on.  Is there a way to set that up?  The Google results are for people who see this as a problem, but for me, it would be a feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible without manually forgetting the network each time from Settings → Wi-Fi. The password is stored on the device and isn't lost automatically.